# C: strtok unexpected behavior

Tags: c, strtok

I am using the following function to read files line-by-line and storing the lines in a linked list.  The files are in the format "file1:file2:file3:file4:file5:file6:".  I am having an issue where after reading file3 strtok returns NULL and the program exits and the other files do not get read.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
void * readerThread(void *args) {

    char * tmp = malloc(strlen(args)+1);
    char * stuff;
    strcpy(tmp,args);
    char * newline = strchr(tmp,'\n');
    if (newline)
        *newline = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr, "All files %s", tmp);
    stuff = strtok(tmp, " :\r\n");

    while(stuff != NULL) {
        char * fileName = stuff;
        FILE * fp;
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s.\n", stuff);
            goto nextFile;
        }

        while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
           //Store the line
        }
    nextFile:
        stuff = strtok(NULL," :\r\n");
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Starting %s\n", stuff);
    }
done:
    reading = 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought we agreed to stop using `goto`

Comment: The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function is *not* thread-safe. For that use `strtok_s`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This isn't a multithreaded question.

Comment: this program is multithreaded but this thread is the only one that accesses the string containing the file names. Would there still be issues? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Dai The `strtok` call is inside a function called `readerThread`. That seem to indicate that the thread safety of `strtok` is relevant information.

Comment: @CSjunkie Yes it might be relevant if you're calling `strtok` in any other thread too

Comment: I note that OP fails to call `free` to release `tmp` before the function returns, nor does the function return anything despite having a return type `void*` in the signature.

Comment: I don't think you want to be saying `char * fileName = stuff;` look into `strcpy`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can you post a link to a description of `strtok_s`? I can't seem to find one.  If it is part of an extended library I probably do not have access to it.

Comment: @CSjunkie what compiler, toolkit, and standard library version are you using?

Comment: note : `if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s.\n", stuff);
            goto nextFile;
        }` ....`fclose(NULL);`<= invalid.

Comment: It's new in C11 (follow the link in my first comment), but other libraries might have similar functions (for example [Visual Studio have a non-standard version of `strtok_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx), and on Linux [there's a `strtok_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) with similar capabilities).

Comment: @Dai I am using gcc as the compiler, the rest I am not sure about because it needs to be very portable and run on multiple machines.

Comment: `getline` is not standard.

Comment: The name of your function is suspicious.  `strtok` is not thread safe.  If there's more than one thread calling it simultaneously, you'll get strange results.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I changed all calls to `strtok(str, delim)` to `strtok_r(str, delim, char **saveptr)` and now my program seg faults after reading the first file

Comment: The last argument should not be a pointer to pointer to `char`, instead you pass a pointer to a variable that is a pointer to `char` using the address-of operator. E.g. `char *saveptr; ...; strtok_r(str, delim, &saveptr);`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you that solved the issue and everything works now.  If you post this as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: the strtok function will stop when it encounters a newline, so there does not need (nor should there be) a newline in the list of delimiters.   the newline, on windows and DOS is a multicharacter item.  so when looking for a newline use strstr( buffer, "\n" ) and check if the returned values is not NULL.  The compiler implementation on the OS will handle the different line ending styles so  "\n" will always work

Comment: If that posted code is the thread function, then the exit should be 'thread_exit( NULL );'  rather than just falling off the end of the functin

Comment: 'goto nextfile;'  that is extremely bad code.  much perfered (in this case) is an 'else' on the 'if (fp == NULL) {' code block with the 'else' ending where the 'nextfile' label is currently located.